# jquery sorting without using plugin

Tags: jquery

I came across this, and thought I'd throw in my 2 cents. Click on the column headers to sort ascending, and again to sort descending.

- Works in Chrome, Firefox, Opera AND IE(8)
- Only uses JQuery
- Does alpha and numeric sorting - ascending and descending

---

```
$('th').click(function(){
    var table = $(this).parents('table').eq(0)
    var rows = table.find('tr:gt(0)').toArray().sort(comparer($(this).index()))
    this.asc = !this.asc
    if (!this.asc){rows = rows.reverse()}
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++){table.append(rows[i])}
})
function comparer(index) {
    return function(a, b) {
        var valA = getCellValue(a, index), valB = getCellValue(b, index)
        return $.isNumeric(valA) && $.isNumeric(valB) ? valA - valB : valA.localeCompare(valB)
    }
}
function getCellValue(row, index){ return $(row).children('td').eq(index).html() }
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Zhd2X/20/

Example with filtering: http://jsfiddle.net/Zhd2X/21/

I use this sorting algo but i face problem when the we sort the column which having same data like boolean column contain true for all rows then it sort data different way every time.

Comment: seems working fine(search with both boolean is true with ascending and descending). I am unable to understand what problem you are facing

Comment: Example:https://jsfiddle.net/NavneetKaur/qeoq7r7p/1/      when I click on "same" column(the column which contain same value) then sorting should not be occur for other fields because each column have same value

Comment: working fine. so didn't get you